# Spring Batch JmsItemReader does not work correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a simple program working with Spring Batch JmsItemReader and сustom ItemWriter. The purpose of the program is to read an ActiveMQ queue. I have setted the commit interval of 25, but it's not working. I am getting items at random intervals to my item writer. I spent the whole day trying to solve this problem, but I can't get through. Please help me. This is my Job config:

```
<batch:job id="reportJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="jmsItemReader"
                         writer="customItemWriter"
                         commit-interval="25">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>


<bean id="jmsItemReader"
      class="org.springframework.batch.item.jms.JmsItemReader">
    <property name="itemType"    value="com.example.Entities.Spitter"/>
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate"/>
</bean>

<bean id="customItemWriter" class="com.example.batch.CustomItemWriter"/>

<bean id="jobRepository"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<bean id="schedulingLauncher" class="com.example.batch.SchedulingLauncher">
    <property name="job" ref="reportJob"/>
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher"/>
</bean>

<task:scheduler id="scheduler" />
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="schedulingLauncher"
                    method="launch"
                    fixed-delay="10000" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

JMS beans:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    <property name="userName" value="admin"/>
    <property name="password" value="admin"/>
</bean>

<bean id="queue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
   <constructor-arg value="JpaQueue"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
   <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
   <property name="defaultDestination" ref="queue"/>
   <property name="receiveTimeout" value="500"/>
   <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
</bean>
```

My ItemWriter:

```
public class CustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Object> {

public void write(List<?> items) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("List size: " + items.size());
    for (Object item: items) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

}

And ShedulingLauncher:

```
public class SchedulingLauncher {

private Job job;
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

public void launch() throws Exception{
    JobParameters jobParams =
            new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("launchTime", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
    jobLauncher.run(job,jobParams);
}
```

Output:

> SimpleJobLauncher:133 - Job: [FlowJob: [name=reportJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{launchTime=1545564286588}]
>
> Executing step: [step1]
>
> List size: 3
>
> Spitter(id=0, userName=UserName0, password=pasword0, fullName=User User0, email=qwer@qwer.com0)
>
> Spitter(id=0, userName=UserName572, password=pasword572, fullName=User User572, email=qwer@qwer.com572)
>
> Spitter(id=0, userName=UserName773, password=pasword773, fullName=User User773, email=qwer@qwer.com773)
>
> SimpleJobLauncher:136 - Job: [FlowJob: [name=reportJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{launchTime=1545564286588}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]

Comment: If there is no message coming quick enough it will end the chunk and do a commit. It won't wait until 25 messages are read. If there is nothing more to read it will stop it won't wait until it read 25 messages.

Comment: @M.Deinum I think <property name="receiveTimeout" value="500"/> in the JmsTemplate is responsible for how long to recive messages. I put "1000", "5000" and get the same result. But the operating time of the Reader increases.

Comment: If there is nothing to receive it will simply assume the end of processing, regardless of the time-out.

Comment: @M.Deinum There are 5,000 messages in my queue.
At each iteration, the reader receives a random number of messages. This can be 1, 3, 5, 11, but is not the number that I want (25).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why and how the number of read items could be random.. A couple of notes though:

- You are setting the `sessionTransacted` on the jms template. Have you set the `readerIsTransactionalQueue` on the `JmsItemReader` as well?
- You are using a `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` which uses a `ResourcelessTransactionManager` by default. This means there is no ongoing transaction when your (transacted) jms session is running. Have you tried to set `sessionAcknowledgeMode = Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED` on the jms template?
- You are using a transactional jms session but I don't see a `JmsTransactionManager` used in your step. Is that intended?
- Related to the previous two points, using a transactional jms session with a non-transactional job repository makes no sense to me. Either disable the `sessionTransacted` on the jms template or use a transactional job repository (in which case you need a `JtaTransactionManager` to synchronize the two transaction managers: jms and database)

If these hints do not help, please share a project with all the code and dependencies on Github (or somewhere else) to be able to reproduce the issue and help you.